# count the sum of difference between two cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

hello i worte a funnction that sums ahe abslute diffrence betwen two cells each time and then i subtact 70000 from the sum
i would like to to this in vba more aesthetic

70000-(IF(D2>0,ABS(D2-C2))+IF(E2>0,ABS(E2-D2))+IF(F2>0,ABS(F2-E2))+IF(G2>0,ABS(G2-F2))+IF(H2>0,ABS(H2-G2))+IF(I2>0,ABS(I2-H2))+IF(J2>0,ABS(J2-I2))+IF(K2>0,ABS(K2-J2))+IF(L2>0,ABS(L2-K2))+IF(M2>0,ABS(M2-L2))+IF(N2>0,ABS(N2-M2))+IF(O2>0,ABS(O2-N2))                                                                    )

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

`=70000-SUMPRODUCT(ABS(D2:O2-C2:N2),N(D2:O2>0))`

Comment: Wow, I was proud of my answer untill I read yours.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit off-topic since you specifically ask for a VBA solution, but this formula-solution would also bring aesthetic and improves calculation:

```
=70000-
 REDUCE(0, COLUMN(C:N),
 LAMBDA(a, b,
        LET(offset,INDEX(2:2,,b+1),
IF(offset>0,
   a+ABS(offset-INDEX(2:2,,b)),
   a))))
```

It loops through column `C:N` (`b`) in the row mentioned (row 2:2 in this case) and checks if the value offset 1 to the right (I used INDEX to not make it volatile, but named it `offset`).
If the value in that row/column+1 is greater than 0 than value `a` becomes `a` + ABS(the value in the row/column+1 - value in that row/column), otherwise `a` stays the same.

Edit:
For if your range might grow/decrease this may be a nice dynamic solution:

```
=70000-LET(range,C2:Z2, 
           cols,DROP(FILTER(COLUMN(range),range<>""),,-1),
REDUCE(0,cols,LAMBDA(a,b,LET(offset,INDEX(2:2,,b+1),IF(offset>0,a+ABS(offset-INDEX(2:2,,b)),a)))))
```

It checks for any values in the range `C2:Z2` (Z could be expanded) and filters out the blanks.
Than it takes all columns in the range minus the last (for the offset calculation purpose).

Note that if there are gaps in your data this would filter those out as well.

Comment: Appreciate the time you took to answer.

Comment: The benefit of this is that it recalculates without having to trigger a macro. If your range would expand/shrink, you can simply change the `column(C:N)` part. (This could also be made dynamical with filter, so it adopts to the number of columns used).

Answer (score 1):

First, based on your formula, you rather only add the absolute difference if the value subtracted from is `>0`. If this is what you want, then you would have something like this:

```
Sub SumAbsDiff()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sum As Double
    
    'This loops from col D to col O
    For i = 4 To 15 Step 1
        If Cells(2, i).Value > 0 Then sum = sum + Abs(Cells(2, i).Value - Cells(2, i - 1).Value)
    Next i
    
    'Change this to the cell you would like to display the value
    Cells(1, 1).Value = 70000 - sum
End Sub
```

Explanation:

Here, we are taking row 2, and then looping over from D until O. Using the loop, we absolute subtract each of them (D-C, E-D, etc) if the `>0` condition satisfy. The result is then add to the `sum` variable (which initialize as 0 by default).

After the loop is done, we just simply use it to subtract from 70,000 and then write it to the cell that we wanted.

As a side note, if your original formula was wrong, and you actually want the sum between each of the absolute differences without the `>0` condition, then removing the `If ... Then` would do the trick.

Comment: Appreciate the time you took to answer

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in VBA using a for loop:

```vb
Sub AbsoluteDifference(n As Double, startCell As String, outputCell As String)
    ' Store variables as double to account for large numbers and decimals
    Dim sum As Double
    sum = 0
    
    'Range until the last filled cell
    For Each i In Range(startCell, Range(startCell).End(xlToRight)).Cells
        If i.Value > 0 Then
            sum = sum + Abs(i.Value - i.Offset(0, -1).Value)
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Save the value to outputCell
    Range(outputCell).Value = n - sum
End Sub

' Run the Main sub to call AbsoluteDifference with parameters
Sub Main()
    Call AbsoluteDifference(70000, "D2", "C3")
End Sub
```

This code produces an identical result to your function.

Comment: Appreciate the time you took to answer.. will try it can i it be writen with dynmic range ?

Comment: The updated answer supports dynamic range in horizontal direction. You can be more verbose by creating a variable for each parameter of AbsoluteDifference within Main

Answer (score 1):

### Sum Up Absolute Differences

[image]

**Static (`C2:O2`)**

```vb
Sub SumUpAbsStatic()
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "C2:O2"
    Const DST_CELL As String = "B2"
    Const INIT_VALUE As Double = 70000
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim Data(): Data = ws.Range(SRC_RANGE).Value
    Dim pValue: pValue = Data(1, 1)
    
    Dim cValue, c As Long, Total As Double
    
    For c = 2 To UBound(Data, 2)
        cValue = Data(1, c)
        If IsNumeric(pValue) Then
            If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
                If cValue > 0 Then Total = Total + Abs(cValue - pValue)
            End If
        End If
        pValue = cValue
    Next c
    
    Total = INIT_VALUE - Total
    
    ws.Range(DST_CELL).Value = Total
    
End Sub
```

**Dynamic (`C2:LastColumn2`)**

```vb
Sub SumUpAbsolute()
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "C2"
    Const DST_CELL As String = "B2"
    Const INIT_VALUE As Double = 70000
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range, cCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(, ws.Columns.Count _
            - .Column + 1).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
            cCount = lCell.Column - .Column + 1
            Set srg = .Resize(, cCount)
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim Total As Double
    
    If cCount > 1 Then
        
        Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value
        Dim pValue: pValue = Data(1, 1)
        
        Dim cValue, c As Long
        
        For c = 2 To cCount
            cValue = Data(1, c)
            If IsNumeric(pValue) Then
                If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
                    If cValue > 0 Then Total = Total + Abs(cValue - pValue)
                End If
            End If
            pValue = cValue
        Next c
    
    End If
    
    Total = INIT_VALUE - Total
    
    ws.Range(DST_CELL).Value = Total
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate  the time you took to answer.. will try it can i it be writen with dynmic range ?